# (International) How does the client independently obtain substantiated expenses/reciepts/ invoices, non-final office-action letters for patents?

Tags: patent-applications, international, office-action, documents, non-final

How does the client find the substantiated expenses/receipts for international and general patent filing/annuities without asking the patent lawyer for a copy? Does one ask for serial numbers, or what kind of ID is it called?

Does every office action have a "serial number?"

What ID numbers are be used to track the progress of a patent application internationally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get itemized statements from your patent attorney. You can ask for a copy of the correspondence from foreign associates or offices acknowledging renewal payments. I am a retired patent agent who did a significant amount of foreign filing and I would have been happy to give clients copies of all correspondence and wire transfers, if asked.

I do not believe there is any common international system for tracking what you are asking about. Office actions do have dates and are usually coded in the data of patent offices by type of action but the coding is jurisdiction depend and events do not carry serial numbers.

Individual cases and applications typically are given attorney docket numbers that end up on most all of the back-and-forth correspondence. They are made up by attorneys and agents for their own record keeping and have no official standing. And are optional.

The core official identifiers are application numbers. With a country prefix they will be unique world-wide. Each continuation or divisional will have a unique application number.

Comment: what is a reasonable fee for obtaining itemized statements and the correspondence from offices acknowledging renewal payments? Is it reasonable to assume a lawyer would do it or does the finance person keep track of these things?

Comment: I don’t have a good answer but it would not be the attorney’s time but an assistant or bookkeeper or paralegal.

Comment: are office actions publicly searchable?

Comment: Yes - after, and assuming, the application has been published.

Comment: Why are trademarks office actions public prior to grant, but patents only available after they had already been published? @GeorgeWhite

Comment: In the U.S. it has been fundamental that patent applications are confidential. Until 2001 the US didn't publish applications.  This gave inventors the option to stop the process before grant/exposure happened. If they were not going to get claims they thought were worth it they could abandon the application.  We trade disclosure to the public for limited exclusivity so it made sense to let the inventor see if and what exclusivity they would get before disclosure. They could keep it a trade secret. The GATT treaty required the US to publish applications at the 18 month point in most cases.

Comment: A patent application teaches others to make and use an invention. You might want to keep to yourself for a while, especially if you can't get protection. Nothing like a trademark.

Comment: How do you search for the office-action paper trail of the patents published after 18 months? @GeorgeWhite (international)

Comment: Try looking it up in Global Dossier https://register.epo.org/help?lng=en&topic=globaldossier.  Public information but not organized for searching.

Comment: Earlier I said the data was searchable - more accurately it is publicly available on line to browse.

Comment: What is the "it" that you specified to look up in a Global Dossier?@GeorgeWhite

Comment: One of the numbers of the patent in question. This is not  forum and I think this set of comments has gone longer than intended by me. Bye